# Norm of a vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'm looking into the norm of a rank-1 matrix $A$.

Because $A$ is a rank-1 matrix, we know that $A=b c^T$, for a $b,c\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For the norm we then have \begin{equation}
\left\Vert A\right\Vert = \max_{x\ne 0}\frac{\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert} = \max_{x\ne 0}\frac{\left\Vert bc^Tx\right\Vert}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert} = \frac{\left\Vert bc^Tc\right\Vert}{\left\Vert c\right\Vert}.
\end{equation}

I think I can further simplify this, but my question is how? Can I write $\left\Vert bc^Tc\right\Vert = \left\Vert b\right\Vert\left\Vert c^Tc\right\Vert$ for example?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Vert ax \Vert = |a|\Vert x \Vert$  for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$c^\top c$ is a scalar.